# toon shadder problems

Tags: materials, toon-shading

Currently, I'm having a lighting error with a toon shader I'm trying to build. My goal was to try and make a stepped honeycomb effect on a toon shader, however the light is not reacting how I hoped it would, and I can't seem to find a fix.

What the shader currently looks like.
[image: Current problem]

What I'm hoping to make. (example from Photoshop)
[image: what I'm trying to make]

Current node setup.
[The problem does not stem from my janky honeycomb pattern, if I plug lets say a voronoi texture into the setup instead I will still get the same weird artifacting.]
[image: node setup]

blend file
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Nothing too wrong, here.. you've just got to make your `Plus`es and `Minus`es consistent across the piece (you could do *everything* the other way round; just not *some* of it):

[image]

The *Length* nodes above do the same as your *Dot-Products*, no problem. The added 'Cell Center' branch might help you get a circular patch of hex-cells. The fields showing `0.866` are typed in as `sqrt(3)/2`.

Comment: Your node setup is working great, however I'm still failing to get the nodes it to react to a light source properly, sorry to take more of your time. Also, I have edited the post to include the blend file if you need it.

Comment: @Dickhead_Jones   Ahh! OK, I'll have a look when I can.

Comment: @Dickhead_Jones Could be tricky.. I'll try and get ahead anyway tomorrow am , but a query....  Do you want the hexes in the plane's space, or the lamp's? (should they look flat on the floor, or as if projected from the lamp). Is the floor always flat? Is the floor always in XY?

Comment: My goal was to use this on some weird objects (Ex: Suzanne), so it probably should look flat on the floor, however. If the other one (projected from a lamp), is easier, please don't hesitate to go with that version since I'm taking so much of your time.

Comment: Don't worry, I don't need this immediately by any means.

Comment: @Dickhead_Jones.. stuck on this one... :(

Comment: @Dickhead_Jones  You could shade the lamp instead, or make a physical gobo for it?  Not quite the same...